# TextView marquee doesn't work, if another textview is changing

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

My Text view is like that

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/current_podcast_name"
    fontPath="@string/font_bold"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/current_podcast_date"
    tools:ignore="Deprecated,HardcodedText,MissingPrefix" />
```

and I add this code
**current_podcast_name.setSelected(true);**

1. Actually, the marquee is working now.
2. But, when I change another textview body, it's doesn't work.

**For example**
I open this tags

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!mSeekbarBroadcastIsRegistered) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(broadcastSeekbarReceiver, new IntentFilter(PowerService.LOCAL_BROADCAST_PODCAST_SEEKBAR));
        mSeekbarBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            updateSeekBarUI(intent);

        }
    };

private void updateSeekBarUI(Intent intent) {
        int counter = intent.getIntExtra("counter",0);
        int mediamax = intent.getIntExtra("mediamax",0);
        int songEnded = intent.getIntExtra("song_ended",0);

        podcastsSeekBar.setMax(mediamax);
        podcastsSeekBar.setProgress(counter);

        //txt_SongTotalDuration.setText(PowerServiceHelper.milliSecondsToTimer(mediamax)); 
        //txt_CurrentDuration.setText(PowerServiceHelper.milliSecondsToTimer(counter));

        if( songEnded == 1 ){
            //do something
        }
    }
```

I receive from media player to current duration and every 1 second I change textview. So, if I open txt_SongTotalDuration , txt_CurrentDuration the marquee doesn't work...

I didn't find any solution.

Thank you

[here this is the problem GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNlnz.gif)

Comment: Can you please show us your source code or a mockup?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question look up :) @cSteusloff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, may this will helpful for you :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/marque_scrolling_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="We publish useful materials from the detailed description without much 'water', to working (audited) examples.Our main task - is to bring the materials most simple and understandable to the reader."
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

In Activity :

```
TextView marque = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.marque_scrolling_text);
        //the same one line of code
        marque.setSelected(true);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: But my code already working for step1.  If  I comment broadcast receiver everything is fine. Thank you

Comment: @OrçunKOBAL i have tried with changing text in each few seconds, it's working fine or you can add marque.setSelected(true); each time after set text in TextView.

Comment: You mean, I must put marquee.setSelected(true); after every each second. If it so, I make it and it's doesn't work :/ I added gif, if you want to see check my question.  @Tushar Mittal